# Is there a logical basis to the distinction between nouns and adjectives? Or can any noun function as an adjective (and v.v.)?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

In logic, the predicate calculus makes no distinction between "it is human" and "it is a human". Should we?

Comment: Those are two different statements.

Comment: "That blood on the floor is a human."

Comment: Compare: "it is canine" with "it is a canine." Behavior, toys, meals, medicine and more can be described as being ***canine***; but they cannot be ***a canine.***

Comment: Isn't there a distinction between attributive and predicative adjectives? Those cases you cite take "canine" in the attributive position (eg. canine medicine), but "canine" cannot be predicated of them (eg. this medicine is canine"??).

Comment: Uh… I think you'll find *this medicine is canine* can be wholly correct.

While broadly only vets and doctors would ever bother, either might say *This is human medicine* or *that's horse medicine* or yes, *that's dog/canine medicine*.

In that context how would it be wrong to say *This medicine is canine* instead of *this is canine medicine*, please?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. We know what the vet and the doctor would mean, I'm not disputing that. I'm not maintaining anything really. I agree that there is a difference between saying "it is canine" and "it is a canine"; but I have the sneaking suspicion that the adjective is the noun in disguise, as it were, that adjectives are just degenerate nouns (in the best sense), and that any noun can go over and be an adjectival modifier. I think the historical development was that we went from "this is a canine" to "it's a canine bone" to "this bone is canine" ... like that.

Comment: What is a "v.v."?